# Querying database by the assigned key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bit of dummy data that I'm trying to query stored in Firebase (Real-time Database) using Swift, and I am a tad bit new to this so I would value your help.

```
{
  "Site-List" : {
    "1" : {
      "address" : "test1",
      "latitude" : 0,
      "live" : false,
      "longitude" : 0,
      "siteName" : "Test1"
    },
    "2" : {
      "address" : "test2",
      "latitude" : 0,
      "live" : false,
      "longitude" : 0,
      "siteName" : "Test2"
    }
  }
}
```

```
var sites: [SiteList] = []

findSite("1")
print(sites)

func findSite(id: String)  {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Site-List")

    ref.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        var newItems: [SiteList] = []
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let siteList = SiteList(snapshot: snapshot) {
                for site in siteList.key {
                    if String(site) == "1" {
                        newItems.append(siteList)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.sites = newItems
    })
}
```

How would I be able to grab everything stored in `"1"` by querying Firebase?

Really appreciate any help or light on the matter.

Kind Regards,
George

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward with a value listener as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events. Give it a spin! If you get stuck, report back with the minimal code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Hi Frank, I've edited my previous post to add the code I use now since reading the docs you supplied. However, I don't know if you by any chance know why my array newItems isn't being put into my sites array. You can see this at `self.sites = newItems`. This doesn't do anything when printing the sites array after assignment, even though newItems is populated.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you show the minimum version of `let siteList = SiteList(snapshot: snapshot) {`? Keep in mind that with the loop you have around that code, the `snapshot` only contains one child of `Site-List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to present this answer which specifically answers the question

> How would I be able to grab everything stored in "1" by querying
>   Firebase?

The answer is; if you know the path to the data you want, you do not need to query.

```
func readSite() {
    let site1Ref = self.ref.child("Site_List").child("1")
    site1Ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let address = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "address").value as? String ?? "No address"
        let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "siteName").value as? String ?? "No site name"
        print(address, name)
    })
}
```

and the output will be

```
test1  Test1
```

That being said, if you actually *want* to query, you need to know what you want to query for. Suppose for example you want to query for all addresses that have a value of *test1*

```
func querySite() {
    let sitesRef = self.ref.child("Site_List")
    let queryRef = sitesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "address").queryEqual(toValue: "test1")
    queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let address = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "address").value as? String ?? "No address"
            let name = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "siteName").value as? String ?? "No site name"
            print(address, name)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output will be

```
test1  Test1
```

If there was more than one result, they will all be printed.

For this query I am using .value which could return more than one child snapshot result in the snapshot, so the snapshot needs to be iterated over to handle each child that was returned.

Note that in my answer the code `self.ref.` points to the root of *my* Firebase, you would set that to point to whatever parent node you use.

Comment: Really appreciate it! Works perfectly and so well detailed :)